# What significance does the moon have for the development of life on earth, and for earth's ecology?

Tags: ecosystem

Planets like Mercury and Venus do not have moons, and they do not appear to harbor (higher) life (forms). How significant is it for the emergence of life on a planet that it has a moon? How does it affect the planet's ecosystem, especially seasons and periods?

Comment: This question is too broad, and to a large extent off-topic for Bio-SE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about astronomy, not biology.


Comment: "our" moon certainly affects tides and so the animals living near the sea shore like barnacles have to face both high tide and low tide during which they become dry.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has this been posted on Astronomy SE? The moderators might take it, although I believe it's a duplicate of something.

Comment: Pluto does, in fact, have moons.

Comment: The part of the question which asks about the ecosystem is utterly on topic, and also interesting. If I'm not mistaken there are theories which attribute the genesis of life to the moon (via tide pools).

Comment: Another factor is that [the moon stabilizes the earth's rotational axis.](http://www.space.com/12464-earth-moon-unique-solar-system-universe.html) Without the moon the axis would significantly tilt over geological periods of time, causing large-scale climate change. So this is an interesting question straddling astronomy and biology. I'd vote to re-open, but I can't.

Answer (score 4):

This question is indeed off topic here but the reason these planets don't have moons is pure chance. Different moons have different origins, some could be meteorites or other drifting bodies that were captured by the planet's gravity, others could be pieces of the planet itself that were spun off before it solidified or from an impact event. Others could be mass ejected from the sun which was captured by the planet and so on and so forth. Whether any of these events occurred in a planet's history is down to chance.

As for ecosystems, since the only planet we know of that has one is the Earth, we have no idea how other ecosystems would be affected by the presence or absence of a moon. The absence of tides would be the most obvious effect but you could also get tidal effects if you have an erratic orbit around the sun or if you have other large bodies close enough to affect you.